# Console. Write text with "link" to class/line

Tags: java, android

Whenever you display a stack trace, you can get a "url-like" text which if you click it opens the appropriate class at the appropriate line.

Is there a possibility to output a text in a way that the console recognizes it and make it clickable like that?

Comment: Most IDE support that feature.

Comment: But how would you format the output so it would recognize it as a "link" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @JEeemy's answer I managed to do this

```
public static void printLinkToThisLine() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3]);
 }
```

I works for me ...

Answer (score 2):

> But how would you format the output so it would recognize it as a "link" ?

You can't and you don't.

AndroidStudio supports that feature. You just need to call
`exception.printStackTrace()` and you should be able to click it in the console tab of IDE.

You will see something like

```
java.lang.Exception
    at whatever.Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

The text inside the bracket will be highlighted and you can click it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using Eclipse, but the Eclipse console parses based on a pattern: FileName.java:lineNumber.

```
  MyFile.java:3
```

Would link you to the 3rd line of whatever class you specified as MyFile.

You could use:

```
 .getClass().getName()
```

to the the name of the file programmatically.

Comment: I'm on AndroidStudio but it doesn't seem to work. I've done this 
`System.out.println("Text :: " + getClass().getName() + ".java:151");` 
but no luck ...